# DOM PDF cutting watermark background when the text is small

Tags: dompdf

i have a watermark bg on a page and that image is being cut off where the text ends. If the text that i write on the page is bigger than the image, it works, else the image gets cut off where the text ends.
Any ideas? 
Thanks.

```css
body  { width: 100%; min-height: 800px }
#container { margin:0 auto !important; width: 750px; overflow: hidden; }
* { font-family: 'Times New Roman' !important; font-size : 14px !important; text-decoration: none !important; margin : 0px;}

#container { width: 100%; }

#watermark { position: fixed; width: 382px; height: 470px; margin-left: 120px; margin-top: 190px; opacity: .07; }

@page {
  margin-left: 3cm !important;
  margin-top: 3cm !important;
  margin-right: 2cm !important;
  margin-bottom: 2cm !important:
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>

  <div id='watermark'><img src='http://placehold.it/1024x768' height='100%' width='100%' /></div>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some sample HTML. Otherwise we can't really help you identify the issue.

Comment: That being said ... if the background image is on an element inside the body then yes, this is expected. If the background image is on the body element then you'll see this in dompdf versions prior to 0.6.0.

Comment: hello, here is one example: http://codeshare.io/aifhu

Comment: (You should go ahead and add that code to your question rather than link to it, especially since your link expires.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the bug is occurring, but the #watermark element appears to be clipped to the size of the #container object even though it is styled with `position: fixed` which should take it out of the normal flow of the document.

The easiest fix would be to move the #watermark element outside the #container element.

```css
body  { width: 100%; min-height: 800px }
#container { margin:0 auto !important; width: 750px; overflow: hidden; }
* { font-family: 'Times New Roman' !important; font-size : 14px !important; text-decoration: none !important; margin : 0px;}

#container { width: 100%; }

#watermark { position: fixed; width: 382px; height: 470px; margin-left: 120px; margin-top: 190px; opacity: .07; }

@page {
  margin-left: 3cm !important;
  margin-top: 3cm !important;
  margin-right: 2cm !important;
  margin-bottom: 2cm !important:
}
```

```html
<div id='watermark'><img src='http://placehold.it/1024x768' height='100%' width='100%' /></div>

<div id='container'>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
  <p>t</p>
</div>
```